# Confluence won't start when changing PostgreSQL cluster

Tags: postgresql, confluence

I'm having an issue where I've upgraded an Atlassian Confluence instance to 6.7.2, and PostgreSQL to 9.6.
In order to use the new PostgreSQL version, I need to change the port that is used in the **confluence.cfg.xml** file. Currently it's defined as `name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/confluence</property>`.
The new cluster version 9.6 runs on port 5433.

So what I did was shutdown Confluence, changed the port from 5432 to 5433, and then start Confluence again. But it never came back up.
So I checked the log file for 9.6 under **/var/log/..** and it was spammed with the following:

`Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 92: "host    all     all   127.0.0.1/32            md5"
2018-04-17 12:03:18 CEST FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "username"
2018-04-17 12:03:18 CEST DETAIL:  Role "username" does not exist.`

How can the user not exist? Apparetly I don't quite understand how PostgreSQL databases and clusters work. My understanding, from an 'upgrade PostgreSQL'-article, was that I install the new version, and upgrade the old to the latest version using `sudo pg_upgradecluster`.

How can the user not exist for the new cluster?

Enlightenment is appreciated :)

Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

Something must have gone wrong during the previous upgrade, after wasting a lot of time trying to solve the error, I decided to run through the upgrade process again - behavior and results were entirely different from last time.
Thanks to noone for helping out ;)